# CSS - Force buttons in a row

Tags: html, css, row

How to force the facebook button and the image in a row? Currently the icon image is in a new row.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=1234567";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-action="recommend" data-font="arial"></div>

<img src="icon.png" alt="Share"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `display` property:

```
.fb-like { 
  display:inline-block;
}
```

You may or may not need to apply it to your image also.

I'd stay away from `float`'s for something so trivial if you can at all help it - but sometimes current structure will dictate that you must (else rewrite the whole structure 'properly').

Answer (score 0):

Either use `display: inline` or `float: left` for that. Both prevent a block container from enforcing a line break after them. If you use the latter, be aware that you need to clear the float afterwards in order to prevent odd layout changes.